# ImportError: No module named xchat

Tags: python, module, irc

```
ImportError: No module named xchat
```

I am getting this error when trying to load a Python script in xchat IRC.  I have several other Python scripts which used the xchat module just fine, but this one script seems to be the only one giving me the error.  Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Also, this is happening with another script as well when I run `python script.py install`. But for other scripts, it has worked fine.

Comment: What details do you need?  Also, this is happening with another script as well when I run "python script.py install".  But for other scripts, it has worked fine.

Comment: Are those scripts all placed in the same location?

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided the actual stack traces that cause the problem, it's hard to say for sure where the problem is.  It's likely that it's being caused by an `import xchat` statement somewhere -- but it'd be reassuring to see that trace, so please edit your question.

When you know which line is causing the problem, then put this line before that line:

```
print 'System path:', '\n\t'.join(sys.path)
```

(you'll need to `import sys` somewhere above that, if you haven't already).

That will print out your system path (`$PYTHONPATH`).  Look in that list and make sure the directory that contains the `xchat` module is present.  If it's not, then that's your problem -- it's likely that something somewhere is either changing or not initializing `$PYTHONPATH` before the invokation of python.

For sanity, do the same thing for the scripts that **do** work to see if the path is behaving correctly in that case.